# Unable to create index in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, error-handling

I am new to Elasticsearch so I know I'm forgetting something but I don't know what.

I ran this code:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
  'index' => 'my_index'
];

// Create the index
$response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

But got this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type":"index_not_found_exception",
        "reason":"no such index",
        "resource.type":"index_or_alias",
        "resource.id":"elasticsearch-i.php",
        "index_uuid":"_na_",
        "index":"elasticsearch-i.php"
      }
    ],
    "type":"index_not_found_exception",
    "reason":"no such index",
    "resource.type":"index_or_alias",
    "resource.id":"elasticsearch-i.php",
    "index_uuid":"_na_",
    "index":"elasticsearch-i.php"
  },
  "status":404
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What makes you think that it is related to PHP after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase How do I debug it?

Comment: Can you tell us what /_cat/indices/ print?

Comment: Well, you could read that error message and then check whether the requested index exists in the ES instance

Comment: @NicoHaase which index instance?

Comment: The ElasticSearch instance you are trying to access - the error message lets me think that the index `my_index` does not exist

Comment: @LeBigCat Nothing just a blank page

Comment: @NicoHaase I thought that was meant to create the index

Answer (score 2):

I had not yet created an index on the elasticsearch server itself.

I have to create it first before I can access it on the php-api

To do that,I run:

```
curl -X PUT -x  "" "http://127.0.0.1:9200"/test
```

on the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of reasons not saving the index. First check your elasticsearch cluster status then try to create the index from any client.

### Check Status of Elasticsearch

#### Health or state of the cluster

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health"`

OR

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/state"`

OR

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_nodes/stats"`

#### Create Index using `curl`

`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/twitter"`

Here is the simple code to create using php:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
    'index' => 'twitter_2'
];

$response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

For complete details check with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_index_management_operations.html